# Spark ouput parquet size with SparkListener

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, monitoring

I am using the `onStageCompleted` of the `SparkListener`, trying to mine out some usefull data from the `accumulables`.

I am interested in finding out the size of output for monitoring purposes.
While the input line count and bytes can be taken from the first stage's "*internal.metrics.input.recordsRead*" and "*internal.metrics.shuffle.write.bytesWritten*" and the output line count can be found from "*internal.metrics.shuffle.write.recordsWritten*" from my penultimate stage, I have no clue how to find the ouput bytes.

Decompressed or compressed is also would an option for me. I'm using Spark 2.10.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at onTaskEnd, there is a **bytesWritten** property. 
Databricks [SparkTaskMetrics](https://github.com/zheyuan28/SparkTaskMetrics) 
might also be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, the bytesWritten and the recordsWritten property is always 0.

Comment: There is another way:
taskEnd.taskInfo.accumulables(6).value.get
[link] (https://tutel.me/c/programming/questions/44528055/counting+the+number+of+output+rows+apache+spark+error+for+outputmetrics) Look at this link for more details.

Comment: True. However, I can only access the "number of output rows" which I already have form the stageEnd. By the way, strangely enough, it appears two times. And there are no accumubale related to the bytes written.